# NLog Truncate syntax

Tags: nlog, uipath, truncate-log

I'm changing NLog.config file for UiPath. I want to increase truncate value to 20000 and I've tried following syntax but it's not working.

```
<variable name="truncated_message" value="${replace:replaceWith=...TRUNCATED:regex=true:inner=${message}:searchFor=^[\s\S]{20000}}"/>
<target type="File" name="WorkflowLogFiles" fileName="${WorkflowLoggingDirectory}/${shortdate}_Execution.log" layout="${time} ${level} ${truncated_message}" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="5" concurrentWrites="true" encoding="utf-8" writeBom="true" />
```

I've also tried following regex but they do not work for me

```
(^(?:\S+\s+\n?){0, 20000}) 
(?\=.\{20000\}).+
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong and how to do set the truncate value to 20000?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941565/193178 ? You can use `${message:truncate=20000}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NLog auto truncate messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368284/nlog-auto-truncate-messages)

Comment: @RolfKristensen Yes I've tried this as 
 
<target type="File" name="WorkflowLogFiles" fileName="${WorkflowLoggingDirectory}/${shortdate}_Execution.log" layout="${time} ${level} ${message:truncate=20000}" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="5" concurrentWrites="true" encoding="utf-8" writeBom="true" /> 
It's not working as well.

Comment: @Julian I've tried this also but i don't know why it's not working for me. Can you please also tell me how can I check the version of Nlog?

Comment: @Maryam If you don't know how to upgrade the NLog nuget-package, then you can always try the legacy approach: `${trim-whitespace:inner=${message:padding=-20000:fixedLength=true}}`

Comment: @RolfKristensen I just tried this and it's still logging 10000 characters.

Comment: @Maryam How many characters to you want? Right now the examples that I have given you will truncate at 20.000 characters (As specfied in your question). You can of course adjust the number to what you like. Are you by any chance writing to a Database-Target?

Comment: I want 20,000 characters. 
No, I'm not writing to a Database-Target.

Comment: @Maryam Guess you have an issue with the copy-paste-key. NLog truncates without issues with both old- and new-style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<nlog>
   <variable name="truncated_message_new" value="${message:truncate=20000}" />
   <variable name="truncated_message_old" value="${trim-whitespace:inner=${message:padding=-20000:fixedLength=true}}" />

   <targets>
      <target type="File" name="WorkflowLogFiles" fileName="C:\temp\nlog/${shortdate}_Execution.log" layout="${time} ${level} ${truncated_message_old}" keepFileOpen="true" openFileCacheTimeout="5" concurrentWrites="true" encoding="utf-8" writeBom="true" />
   </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="WorkflowLogFiles" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

It only saves 20000 characters:

```
var test = string.Empty.PadLeft(40000, '*');
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("test").Info("Doing hard work! {Action}", test);
```

Comment: I tried this for 5000 and it's working. Also, I just got to know that UiPath doesn't allow more that 10,000 characters so that's why it wasn't working with 20,000 limit. Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate that :) I'm marking it as a solution

Comment: Just a thought what maximum truncate limit that we can set in Nlog?

Comment: I guess it is 1 or 2 gigabytes. But you might hit other funny limits first.